# access: autonumber field but not parallel with primary key

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm creating a customer help form (for reporting computer support)

After inserting a Customer in the database, a number should be generated like: WO: 00001

The number should be unique, because when the same Customer has another job, it should be for example: WO: 00012 assuming there were a few clients before him.

What should I do?

Comment: Do you want the series of WO job numbers to be in sequence, or do you not care if there are gaps?

Answer (score 2):

Just use an `autonumber` integer field. You can append the `WO` and add the leading zeros in your select or at render time.

Comment: I read that autonumbering is not a good idea, also the Customer ID is also unique and I get errors creating a new autonumber field, like this allready excists.

Comment: The new autonumber field does not go in the Customer table; it goes in the HelpRequest table (or whereever it is you record the help requests).